# Can not get environment variables "ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY" in integrated terminal of vscode. Is anyone else has met this problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I am using electron-quick-start project to learn electron, and when I open this project in vscode and execute `yarn install`, some exception has been throwed out:

```
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\user_home\Downloads\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\electron
Output:
RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND npm.taobao.org
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user_home\Downloads\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\got\source\request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\Users\user_home\Downloads\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\source\index.js:37:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I have set the system environment variables following electron's official proxy setting guide:

```
ELECTRON_MIRROR="https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/"
ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY=true
```

by debuging the node_modules/electron/install.js, I found that the process.env.ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY is not value I have set but undefined. but when I debug this script in powershell opened from the explorer, process.env.ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY print out the right value I have set.